# Get Font Size List in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

This code prints out every entry in the Font Size list combo box in Excel 2007 :

```
Sub FontSizeList()

Dim combo As CommandBarComboBox

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 1 To Application.CommandBars("Formatting").Controls.Count
    If Application.CommandBars("Formatting").Controls(i).Caption = "&Font Size:" Then
        Set ctl = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").Controls(i)
        For j = 1 To ctl.ListCount
            Debug.Print ctl.List(j)
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

However, when I run the same code in Powerpoint 2007 the List is Empty?  How can I intialize  the Font Size combo box in Powerpoint VBA?  I have checked both Font Size properties 'Visible' and 'Enabled', and they are both set to True.

Thanks very much

Joe

Comment: are you not using `Option Explicit`? If not, then you will indeed regret it someday...

Comment: Just ran it in PowerPoint 2003, works fine there...

Comment: Thanks, Yes I am using 'Option Explicit'.  I'm using Powerpoint 2007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code on both Excel and PowerPoint 2007.

On PowerPoint, FontList and FontSize are unselectable (dark grey) if no text bloc (or drawing) is selected. That could explain why the ListCount is still 0 when debugging.

That could also explain why it does work on PPT 2003 because you do not have the ribbon and maybe FontSize and FontList are already selected.

Unfortunately, even while selecting a bloc text, i did not manage to have a ListCount > 0. I'd have to look at it further.

Max

Comment: Thanks JMax - Yes, thats where I got to..  even after selecting a shape and the Font Size list is enabled, the Font Size List is not populated.

Comment: I didn't manage to do it by myself. Maybe you could try this solution : http://vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37338. Btw, i've tried this solution and it worked : http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00594.htm. Hope it could help.

Comment: Thanks for the http://vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37338 link, seems like I'll have to go Old School!